# Array is empty, no data after for loop added

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using redis and nodejs for the first time, without success. Trying to loop insert data but got an empty array.

```
const redis = require("redis");

const client = redis.createClient({
  retry_strategy: function(options) {
    if (options.error && options.error.code === "ECONNREFUSED") {
      // End reconnecting on a specific error and flush all commands with
      // a individual error
      return new Error("The server refused the connection");
    }
    if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
      // End reconnecting after a specific timeout and flush all commands
      // with a individual error
      return new Error("Retry time exhausted");
    }
    if (options.attempt > 10) {
      // End reconnecting with built in error
      return undefined;
    }
    // reconnect after
    return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
  },
});

var data_value = {
        id: '235235',
        totalrv: 'WAIT',
        product: 'productName2',
        url: 'url2',
        process: 'proc',
        task: 'msg'
    };

client.set("key0", JSON.stringify(data_value));
client.set("key1", JSON.stringify(data_value));
client.set("key2", JSON.stringify(data_value));
client.set("key3", JSON.stringify(data_value));
client.set("key4", JSON.stringify(data_value));

//client.get("key2", redis.print);

var logger_data = {
        logger: []
    };

client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
        var values_v = client.get(keys[i].toString(), function(err, val) {
            // console.log(logger_data);
            // data is exist ...
            logger_data.logger.push(JSON.parse(val));
        });
    }
});

// empty data
console.log(logger_data);
```

I wrote 2 print data result, in the loop it's working ok, but end of function, there are no data in array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: no, it's not working in for loop ... i mean :(

Comment: Indeed, it's not working because you're altering it in an asynchronous callback

Comment: but how i can do that ? i tried a lot of example code but none working for this situation.

Comment: Look at the linked question and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call. Put the functionality you need inside the callback

Comment: Hey i just found out it's working now ... thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can call a function inside the callback if you want to print the `logger_data` with values outside the asynchronous callback,  like this

```
function printLoggerData(){
 console.log(logger_data);
}

client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
        var values_v = client.get(keys[i].toString(), function(err, val) {
            // console.log(logger_data);
            // data is exist ...
            logger_data.logger.push(JSON.parse(val));
            // calling the function here so that it contains the latest values
            printLoggerData(); 
       });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with help of CertainPerformance, it's now working in asynchronous.
Thank you very much ...

```
async function getMessage () {
    var logger_data = {
        logger: []
    };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);

            for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
                var values_v = client.get(keys[i].toString(), function(err, val) {
                    logger_data.logger.push(JSON.parse(val));
                    resolve(logger_data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

async function main() {
    let message = await getMessage();
    console.log(message);
}

main();
```